# i did mapping with if else condition in init.vim for float term plugin but got an error

Tags: vim, editor, vim-plugin, neovim

for plugin in `neovim` called `float-term` actually you don't need to know the plugin at all , it's just error i got from mapping with conditional statements , i want to do conditional mapping like below , if i am do something wrong in function then write right function please.

**if you think that my whole method is wrong , that also can be happen then give me right path**

for javascript

```
nnoremap <F5> :FloatermNew node %<CR>
```

for c

```
nnoremap <F5> :FloatermNew gcc % && ./a.out<CR>
```

for c++

```
nnoremap <F5> :FloatermNew g++ % && ./a.out<CR>
```

for python

```
nnoremap <F5> :Floaterm python3 %<CR>
```

Now i want that these all working with one shortcut `F5`.

**i done like this but get an error**

```
nnoremap <expr> <F5> My_mapping()

function! My_mapping
    if &filetype ==# 'c'
        nnoremap <F5>:FloatermNew gcc % && ./a.out <CR>
    elseif &filetype ==# 'c++'
        nnoremap <F5>:FloatermNew g++ % && ./a.out <CR>
    elseif &filetype ==# 'js'
        nnoremap <F5>:FloatermNew node % <CR>
    elseif &filetype ==# 'py'
        nnoremap <F5>:FloatermNew python3 % <CR>
    else
        nnoremap <F5><CR>
    endif
endfunction
```

> error

```
Error detected while processing /home/visrut/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line  208:
E123: Undefined function: My_mapping
n  <F5>        * My_mapping()
line  220:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
```

**can anyone fix error? or if i am totally wrong with this method then can anyone define new way to do this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew node %<CR>
autocmd FileType c nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew gcc % && ./a.out && rm a.out<CR>
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew g++ % && ./a.out && rm a.out<CR>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew python3 %<CR>
autocmd FileType typescript nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<esc>:FloatermNew ts-node %<CR>
```